# Unable to get request parameters in Servlet filter from JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, servlet-filters

I'm unable to pass userName from below JSP and access it in Servlet filter. Below are the JSP & Filter. I have tried accessing using request Paramter,attribute and ParameterNames, but getting only null values.
I have run the application in debug mode and it is hitting the filter after I press submit button.
Please let me know if I'm doing anything wrong.
JSP:

```
 <html>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
        <head>

        </head>
        <body>
            <p><bean:message key="logonForm.info.text"/></p>
            <form action="/uchpweb/login.do" name="login_form" method="post">
                <div id="layLogInContainer">
                    <div id="layLogInFields" class="inputAreaLight">
                        <b>UserName</b><br>
                        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" tabindex="1" size="10" maxlength="10" /><br />
                    </div>
                    <div id="layLogInButtonBar" class="btnBar">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>`
```

Filter:

```
public class UserFilter implements Filter {

    FilterConfig config;
    Boolean flag;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private Logger log = ResourceLocator.getInstance().getLogger(this);

    public void init(FilterConfig config) {
        this.config = config;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {


        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpSession httpSession = httpRequest.getSession();


        Enumeration<String> params = httpRequest.getParameterNames();
        while(params.hasMoreElements()){
            String name = params.nextElement();
            String value = request.getParameter(name);
            log.debug("Name : ",name);
            log.debug("value : ",value);
        }

        if (request.getParameter("username") == null && (request.getAttribute("username") == null)) {
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher1 = request.getRequestDispatcher("/logon.jsp");
            if (dispatcher1 != null) {
                dispatcher1.forward(request, response);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

web.xml

```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>CommonUserContextFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>UserContextFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CommonUserContextFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CommonUserContextFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CommonUserContextFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

[image: ***Please click on this link to find httpRequest***]

Comment: Please share your web.xml

Comment: so r u getting null using both Servlet and Http requests?Can u try directly fetching from httpRequest,without using Enumeration?

Comment: so when exactly is the filter code hit in debug mode?

Comment: Shivam, Yes I'm getting null values for both servlet and Http. The Filter code is hit after I press submit button

Comment: I see that your filter class is not in a package. Can you please move your filter class into a package. For Example com.*.* and so on . May be my comment does not make sense, but can you please try it

Comment: Avinash.. I have intentionally removed it :) due to company privacy issues.Yes I have placed them in a package and it is hitting the filter.

Comment: Also what is the url that is called when you click on submit button. Can you please provide the url

Comment: http://localhost:9080/xxx/logon.jsp and it is a post method and I see username=dd&submit=submit being passed in Request body